# ArcGIS Portal installation on workgroup machine and AD authentication

Tags: arcgis-server, arcgis-10.3, installation, arcgis-portal, configuration

We have typical situation in our new environment:

1. We have ArcGIS Server10.3.1 in a Domain.
2. We are setting up ArcGIS Portal 10.3.1 on a DMZ location. As per security they will not add the portal server to the domain, so It remains workgroup.
3. Server and Portal can communicate with each other through HTTPS.

Can we federate Server with Portal?

Portal need to be authenticated with Active Directory. Is it doable?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As long as Portal and server can communicate over the required ports (6443,7443,etc. not just https), then yes, you can federate Portal and Server.

As long as portal can reach the domain controller,  then yes you can use AD. You do not have to add the Portal machine to the domain, but you need to be able to pass credentials from the Portal application to the domain controller for authentication.

Comment: Thank you Ben, I will try and update here the procedure.